# Associative Multi-Dimensional PHP Array Loop

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array

I am new to Multi-Dimensional arrays and working on building my php skills as well.  I have an associative array which I want to get the nested elements of the array but not have to worry about the multi-dem arrays name.  Example:

```
Array ( 
[cur_wea_array] => Array ( [status] => current [day] => 0 ) 
[for_wea_array0] => Array ( [status] => current_forecast [day] => 1 ) 
[for_wea_array1] => Array ( [status] => current_forecast [day] => 2 )
[for_wea_array3] => Array ( [status] => current_forecast [day] => 3 ) )
```

I would like to not to have to worry about the cur_wea_array element and just loop through and get the status element.
Is there a way you can loop [%wildcard][day] or something?  So I can get all the status or day elements without having to specify [cur_wea_array] and [for_wea_array0]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach ( $array as $inner_array )
{
    echo $inner_array['day']; // or $inner_array['status'];
}
```

This is a basic [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) example specific to your case, every time the loop iterates, `$inner_array` is populated with each inner array

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a [`foreach` loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach ($array as $array_element) 
{
    // your $array_element contains the inner array
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you only want the array keys, you can access them with something like:

```
$array_keys = array_keys($array);
```